# Is it a bad idea to use a svg as a background image for a website file size wise?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, vector, svg

I need to save out some images for a website project at work. These images will span the full background of the site using background-cover. I first thought that svg would be the correct choice but I couldn't get the file size to anything acceptable. It turned out that jpg or png seemed like it was a better bet now because I could compress it down much smaller.

At work I am being told that I should be using svg for this project but from the research I have done I don't see a way to compress down to a reasonable size. Am I missing some technique to get svg to scale much smaller?

Comment: is the svg file zipped?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I saved the image out as svg from Illustrator and then used another service to compress further because I was reading that Illustrator does a poor job at compressing this file type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test the compatibility on diferent target devices, mainly mobil ones to see if your background works.

According to this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css It is now safe to use it inline.

If the image is a flat design I would use a png. I would not use a svg for background, just for diagrams. I do not think a background needs to be "that" scalable. But this is just me.

The file size of a svg depends on how many nodes you have, gradients, internal incrusted stuff, exessive code. So it is hard to know what is the image about.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question of file size very well

Comment: Oh... File size... Right.